# How to use traceroute on CI systems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, codeship, rails-traceroute

I tried running

```
FAIL_ON_ERROR=1 bin/rake traceroute
```

on codeship, but it was complaining that it couldn't find the rake task traceroute, giving me the "Don't know how to build task" error message. It works on my machine (tm), but not on codeship. What's going wrong?

Comment: GitHub issue for this: https://github.com/amatsuda/traceroute/issues/26

Answer (score 1):

Traceroute is only available in the development environment. The Setup Commands I had had included

```
export RAILS_ENV=test
```

To get traceroute running, I ran traceroute in the development environment by changing the command for running traceroute to

```
RAILS_ENV=development FAIL_ON_ERROR=1 bin/rake traceroute
```